# I have a problem about the updated version of R

Tags: r

I have a question about the updated version of R. Since I want to update the R and R studio to the latest version, I delete the existed R and R Studio, and then download the latest version from the R and R studio website. But I had a problem. I did update all the packages, and make sure that the random number generator is the latest. But when I was doing a data analytics question in R, I get the wrong result again and again, that is different from my friend's result that is correct answer. I am sure that My code is correct, since my friend helped me check my code by running my code on her R and my code has the correct results. I guess it's the updating issue. But I still do not solve it. Is there anyone can help me with this? Really appreciate!

Comment: Hi GuiW! Please take a look to this post and improve your question so you can get better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you have different R versions then different samplers may be getting used: https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2019/04/20. But your question does not have enough details to be answerable.